# The max number of querys in the script !

Tags: sql

i am asking about the max number of querys in the page !

i have 6 querys in my script

```
select * from settings //my website settings
select * from articales where art_id = '' // topics
select * from tags // tags
select * from categories // categories
select * from sub_categories
```

so the big scripts like vbulletin and wordpress , etc

How many querys, almost ? !

i am sorry for my language but i want to know my querys is more ? or they good

to save my server health , i have more visitors

and please if any one can tell me , how i can get data from multiple tables in one query ?

Example :

i want get all data from posts and from tags

where post id equal '10'

thank you ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you fetching your entire database at once?

Anyway you can just select them all in a single query:

```
SELECT * FROM settings, articales, tags, categories, sub_categories ...
```

Of course you'll want to join them and group them in some way otherwise you'll simply have a huge recordset of mixed up junk.

Regarding your posts and tags join, something like this would make sense, though I have no idea how your tags and posts are related in your schema

```
SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN tags on posts.tag_id = tags.tag_id WHERE posts.post_id = 10
```

If you have a many-to-one tags-to-posts assignment, look into [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) for your query. Ex: `FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d')`

Comment: Thenk you very much alien 
it's good idea i selected all in one query
and tested it working fine !